# Calling the same function with ListBox or ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I have series of listboxes and comboboxes that I want to update, so that the items listed are the same as those listed in a `IEnumerable<string>`. I do understand that data binding might help, but I think it could be a bit of a struggle now, and I'd rather avoid it.
I wrote something like this:

```
    public static void UpdateListboxWithStrings(
        ListControl listcontrol, 
        IEnumerable<string> stringlist)
    {
        Object listcontrolitems;
        if (listcontrol is ListBox)
        {
            listcontrolitems =
                ((ListBox)listcontrol).Items;
        }
        else if (listcontrol is ComboBox)
        {
            listcontrolitems =
                ((ComboBox)listcontrol).Items;
        }
        else
        {
            //// Wrong control type.
            //// EARLY EXIT
            return;
        }
        int itemscount = listcontrolitems.Count;
        /// More code here...
    }
```

... And troubles begin. Depending on what I add / remove, `listcontrolitems` appears undefined, or must be initialized, or it doesn't have properties such as `Count`.

How do you write a function that works with a combobox or in a listbox without code duplication?

LE. It is a Windows Application, NET Framework 4.5 using `System.Windows.Forms`. I want to add / remove items, count, get and set selection. Also, there might be duplicates. So converting to items to strings won't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "work with a combobox"? If you have a new method you want to implement, extend the original control. Alternatively you could pass the control to a user-defined method.

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? It matters. The correct answer depends heavily on the context. If you're using Winforms, you cannot assign the same collection type from the two different `ListControl` sub-classes to the same variable; they aren't related. You can, however, dereference the collection in the type-specific branch of your code, saving the `Count` property to an `int` local variable, which of course can be shared.

Comment: @PeterDuniho As said in edited answer, Windows Application.

Comment: "Windows Application" is a project type, not a GUI framework. If you would just be specific about the types you are using (i.e. fully qualified names, including namespaces), then we could tell what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterDuniho My bad. I am using System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF? Which `ListControl` class? `System.Windows.Forms.ListControl`?

Comment: `ComboBox.Items` has a different data type from `ListBox.Items`. They're not the same thing, and you probably can't treat them as the same thing. OTOH, they _do_ both implement the `IList`, 
 `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable` interfaces.

Comment: Besides, there are only two types of control you're dealing with. I would write two methods, and get them both to work. Only then would I consider refactoring the two methods to reduce duplication.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am adding, removing, counting, reading ElementAt(x).ToString(). These seem to me common operations for any IEnumerable. Also, I have the method for ListBox, and it covers some 3 screens. It felt bad duplicating it.

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not have features to add and remove. `IList` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a convenient way, unless you only need the features that are available in the `IList` type. In that case, you can skip the wrapper described below and just declare the `items` local variable as `IList`, assigning it directly to the `Items` property in each control-type-specific `if` branch.

If all you needed was the `Count` property value, you could assign a local `int` variable in each type-specific branch (i.e. in the `if` statement blocks).

But you state that you want to actually manipulate the collections. The `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Items` and `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.Items` collections are two completely different, unrelated types. So if you can't use `IList`, the only way you would be able to share code that manipulates them would be to wrap the collections in a new type that understands both.

For example:

```
abstract class ListControlItems
{
    public abstract int Count { get; }
    public abstract int Add(object item);
    public abstract void RemoveAt(int index);
    // etc.
}

class ListBoxControlItems : ListControlItems
{
    private ListBox.ObjectCollection _items;

    public ListBoxControlItems(ListBox.ObjectCollection items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public override int Count { get { return _items.Count; } }
    public override int Add(object item) { return _items.Add(item); }
    public override void RemoveAt(int index) { _items.RemoveAt(index); }
    // etc.
}
```

Do the same thing for a `ComboBoxControlItems` type. Then in your handler, you can create the appropriate abstract type, and use that to manipulate the collections:

```
public static void UpdateListboxWithStrings(
    ListControl listcontrol, 
    IEnumerable<string> stringlist)
{
    ListControlItems items;

    if (listcontrol is ListBox)
    {
        items = new ListBoxControlItems(((ListBox)listcontrol).Items);
    }
    else if (listcontrol is ComboBox)
    {
        items = new ComboBoxControlItems(((ComboBox)listcontrol).Items);
    }
    else
    {
        //// Wrong control type.
        //// EARLY EXIT
        return;
    }

    int itemscount = items.Count;
    /// More code here...
}
```

Comment: Looks promising in theory, but indeed it feels easier to duplicate the code.

Comment: Yes, the above is not as convenient. Did you try using `IList`? It wasn't clear from your question what operations you need, but almost everything that either of the control-specific collections can do, the `IList` interface can do also (the main thing I think is missing is the `AddRange()` method). One major argument in favor of abstraction is the usual "DRY": as soon as you copy/paste code, now you have two different places that if either ever changes, you need to remember to change the other as well.

Comment: Nah, there's also selection to deal with, and that is quite different from one box to the other. The selection part supports the case for keeping listbox code separate from combobox.